# How To get below out put

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table

[image]

from the table I need the sum of amount field which is having distinct **ReID** Count >=4  against the BeReID column ID.

The result of the table as shown below. Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Luckily, they all have a count >= 4, so we can ignore that requirement.

Comment: @Strawberry in his sample data, yes, but maybe in his table no :)

Comment: `SELECT bereid, SUM(amount) FROM my_table GROUP BY bereid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT reid) >= 4` The rest of the problem is a display issue, (most of which is) best resolved in application code.

Comment: @Valerica In which case the sample data is not representative. I.e., it's not a 'sample'.

Comment: Did you try anything before asking other people to write it for you?

Comment: @Valerica you are correct. this is sample data... but in my table , I have ReID count less than 4 also.

Comment: @JajulaSiva then that should have been explained in your post, if you don't show all scenarios of the data.

Comment: @ Romain Bar9     ReID column having distinct ID's and same ID's as well. If ReID distinct ID's  count >=4 against BeReID ID then I need count as shown in below image.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    pid
    ,A.BeReID
    ,B.Amount
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        BeReID
        ,SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM your_table 
    GROUP BY BeReID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ReID) >= 4
) B
    ON A.BeReID = B.BeReID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

`SELECT t.PID, t.BeReID, t2.SUM
FROM t
JOIN
(SELECT PID, BeReID, SUM(Amount) as SUM
FROM t
GROUP BY BeReID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ReID) >= 4
) as t2
ON t.BeReID = t2.BeReID;`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/811481/11

With the second select you get your sum by BeReID and with the join allows you to set this sum to all your rows.
The having part is for your "having distinct ReID Count >=4 against the BeReID column ID" condition